# Как запустить проект с переменными Gitlab CI registry?

Tags: django, docker, gitlab-ci, .env, ci-cd

У меня есть Gitlab раннер, и сейчас я настраиваю CI/CD, используя один гайд. В нем говорится, что раннеру нужно, чтобы имена образов в `docker-compose.yml` были названы так:

```
$CI_REGISTRY/organisation/path-to-project/project_image:$CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG-$CI_COMMIT_SHA
```

Я поместил это значение в переменную в файле `.env`. Но теперь, когда я запускаю `docker compose up` - выскакивает ошибка - говорит, что `$CI_REGISTRY`, `$CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG` и `$CI_COMMIT_SHA` не установлены. Что делать в этом случае? До подключения CI/CD все работало нормально.

```
level=warning msg="The \"CI_REGISTRY\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."       
level=warning msg="The \"CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
level=warning msg="The \"CI_COMMIT_SHA\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."     
Error response from daemon: no such image: organisation/path-to-project/project_image:-: invalid reference format
```

В то же время `docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY` в `before_script` в `.gitlab-ci.yml` работает и значения переменных откуда-то вычисляются.

```
image: docker/compose:alpine-1.28.0

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

before_script:
  - apk add make
  - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
  - cp $ENV $(pwd)/src/.env

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - make build push
  tags:
    - job:build
  only:
    - main
  environment:
    name: production

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - make pull down migrate up
  tags:
    - job:deploy
  only:
    - main
  environment:
    name: production
```

`$ENV` в `before_script` - это переменная из настроек гитлаба.

Вот `docker-compose.yml` (`${IMAGE_NAME}` - переменная из `.env`):

```
services:
  app1:
    build: .
    image: ${IMAGE_NAME}
    env_file:
      - .env
    # ...

  app2:
    build: .
    image: ${IMAGE_NAME}
    env_file:
      - .env
    # ...
```

Можете сказать, что я делаю не так? Только начал разбираться с CI/CD.